# how do I write the data to NFC Card/Tag dynamically using NFC writer?

Tags: nfc, lib-nfc

I need to implement something like NFC virtual shopping store.

But problem is I don't want to use mobile phone as NFC reader.

First thing I am learner :)

Scenario is I have five art pieces and 50 visitors

So I am thinking I will implement 5 NFC card reader and writer and 50 NFC tags

All NFC TAGS are already filled up with user data like email, email, phone

And all NFC reader and writer are setup with art pieces.

User will come to gallery and tap NFC TAG on the required art piece or somethings

PROBLEM IS HERE

"can I update NFC tag data dynamically when he tapping?"

Like adding product id into the NFC tag... and product id is fixed for that reader or writer

So at time of tapping NFC writer will write the product id (which fixed for each writer) into the NFC tag

Is that possible?

Sorry I am not good in explaining problem in short ... :)

Please let me know, it is possible or not .. and I am on right track or not

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: yes you can, but it is not very practical.
You would have to connect all five card readers/writers to a controller (like PC) and implement writing logic there.
Five NFC readers/writers are also very expensive, minimum 50€ for once piece.

More common scenario would be:
Each art piece has its own NFC tag. This tag is read-only (so no one can change data) and contains information about art piece (id, price, ...).
Each visitor has his own NFC enabled phone (Android, Windows Phone) with NFC application you provided. When user scans NFC tag, art piece information is stored in application.

In case you cannot use NFC enabled phone:
Store only unique ID on visitor NFC tag and have user data stored in central database server. 
When user taps NFC tag, controller adds record to database with user ID.
This way you have all the data tied to the user stored in one location and you do not have to write back to user tag.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.. but can you please tell what do you mean by controller in the second approch?

Comment: can you please explain what is controller??

Comment: A device that controls NFC reader/writer (is connected to). It can be PC or Raspberry PI, etc...
It communicates with reader/writer over RS-232 or USB serial port. You can use libnfc for this communication.